# Unable to retrieve HTML content from XML tags while parsing XML in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an online XML with the following HTML formatting tag within the XML tag:

```xml
<synopsis>
  <!--[CDATA[&lt;p&gt;
&lt;span style=&quot;color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: arial; font-size: 13px; white-space: pre-wrap;&quot;&gt;Yeh Jawaani Hai Deewani is a story of the exhilarating and terrifying journey of four characters &amp;ndash; Bunny, Naina, Aditi and Avi, as they navigate through their youth; from their carefree laughter as they set off on a holiday together in their colleges days, until their bittersweet tears as they watch the first of their bunch get married.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;]]-->
</synopsis>
```

The content between "synopsis" tags is encoded as HTML. It want to show the content with HTML formatting in my WebView, so I stored this value in an arrya while parsing, and then retrieved from the arra as NSString and used WebView loadHTMLString with that string variable. but the content is not showing up with HTML formatting; it is showing as it is in the synopsis tag.

**EDIT:**

This was the HTML content before encoding in the XML synopsis tag:

```html
<synopsis>
<body style=\"background:black;\">
<p>
<span style=\"color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: arial; font-size: 13px; white-space: pre-wrap;\">Yeh Jawaani Hai Deewani is a story of the exhilarating and terrifying journey of four characters &ndash; Bunny, Naina, Aditi and Avi, as they navigate through their youth from their carefree laughter as they set off on a holiday together in their colleges days, until their bittersweet tears as they watch the first of their bunch get married.
</span>
</p>
</body>
</synopsis>
```

I wanted to parse data between "synopsis" tags but was unable to do it.